# Inject instance in all objects using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

```
class A {
    public A() {
    }
}

class B {
    @Inject
    @Named("A")
    private A a;

    public B() {
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class AModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("A")
    public A providesA() {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

We are doing like this:

```
AModule module = new AModule();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
B b = injector.getInstance(B.class);
System.out.println(sample.getA());
```

But we have many classes with A as dependency and we don't want to add this code every time we create an instance.

So, is there any way to auto inject instance of A while creating instance of B?

Comment: I want to avoid code like this: `AModule module = new AModule();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
B b = injector.getInstance(B.class);` It would be great if I can create instance of B with auto inject.

Comment: That's what my question is. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: My ideal code would be: `AModule module = new AModule(); Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module); injector.injectNamedSomething(); ` once and then,   `B b = new B(); b.getA();` as I have already used Named injector.

Comment: My instance creator code shouldn't worry about injector as I already defined it once.

Comment: In your example code, `A` *will* be "auto-injected", as it has a zero-argument constructor. Can you provide more details about the exact problem you're facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (usually) not correct to create as many top-level Injectors as you suggest in your question. Injector creation is expensive, and once Guice has calculated your graph of dependencies, you should not need to calculate it all over again. In general there should be one top-level Injector across your application, and any other Injectors are either "child injectors" or parts of a separate and unrelated object graph.

In order from "worst" to "best":

### Keep the Injector statically

If you are introducing DI into a lot of existing or legacy code, then it may be tempting to stash the Injector into a publicly-accessible object.

```
public class InjectorHolder() {
  private InjectorHolder() {}  // Not instantiable

  private static Injector injector;

  public static void initializeInjector() {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new AModule(), new BModule(), andSoOn());
  }

  public static Injector get() {
    return injector;
  }

  public static B getB() {
    return injector.getInstance(B.class);
  }
}
```

At this point you can call `InjectorHolder.get().getInstance(B.class)` or `InjectorHolder.getB()` from the parts of the app you've migrated so far. Note that this may be difficult to test, and relies on Guice directly from across your application—both of which are not ideal.

### Use Guice static injections

Guice provides [a few features for static injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections), notably the method call [`requestStaticInjection(Class... types)`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#requestStaticInjection-java.lang.Class...-). With a call to that in your module, Guice will inject static members that have `@Inject` annotations as soon as the Injector is created.

```
public class StaticBModule extends AbstractModule() {
  @Override public void configure() { requestStaticInjection(BFactory.class); }
}

public class BFactory() {
  @Inject @Named("B") private static Provider<B> bProvider;

  public B get() {
    return bProvider.get();
  }
}
```

Now you can call `new BFactory().get()` instead of `new B()`, and it'll all go to the same injector. Naturally, you could also allow `new B()` instead if you put a `static Provider<A>` into your `B` class and request static injection for that instead, or you could keep your `BFactory` as an instance and replace it during tests to issue the `B` instances you need. At that point, you might as well just retrofit the classes that call `new BFactory()` to instead include a `static Provider<B>`, and have them inject statically, and then migrate those, all the way up until you have a full DI solution (explained below).

You may also consult [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18454790/1426891), which has an example.

### Ideal solution

You've shown us `A` and `B`, but presumably some other class `C` uses many instances of `B`, and maybe `YourApplication` (which contains your static `main` method) uses `C`. You can use Guice to create an instance of `YourApplication` or `C`, and then `C` can contain an injected `Provider<B> bFactory`. Then, rather than call `new B()`, you can call `bFactory.get()` to create as many `B` instances as you might need.

This way, your classes depend on exactly what they depend on, with no static state or references to Guice other than at the top level.